# Assigning x and y value from CSV to MatplotLib scatter heatmap

Tags: python, numpy, csv, matplotlib

For a current project, I am planning to set up a scatter heatmap with MatplotLib. The data for xs and ys shall be fed from a CSV file with two columns that both include float numbers.

On this basis, I have not yet figured out a way to correctly assign the CSV columns to xs and xy. The example below is, for instace, yielding the error `TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable`. Does anyone know a smart tweak to make this heatmap work?

The corresponding code looks like this:

```
# Importing CSV
df = open("heatmap.csv", "r", encoding="utf8")

# Assigning X, Y
xs = df[0]
ys = df[1]
resolution = 250

# Heatmap calculations
def data_coord2view_coord(p, vlen, pmin, pmax):
    dp = pmax - pmin
    dv = (p - pmin) / dp * vlen
    return dv


def nearest_neighbours(xs, ys, reso, n_neighbours):
    im = np.zeros([reso, reso])
    extent = [np.min(xs), np.max(xs), np.min(ys), np.max(ys)]

    xv = data_coord2view_coord(xs, reso, extent[0], extent[1])
    yv = data_coord2view_coord(ys, reso, extent[2], extent[3])
    for x in range(reso):
        for y in range(reso):
            xp = (xv - x)
            yp = (yv - y)

            d = np.sqrt(xp**2 + yp**2)

            im[y][x] = 1 / np.sum(d[np.argpartition(d.ravel(), n_neighbours)[:n_neighbours]])

    return im, extent


fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2)

for ax, neighbours in zip(axes.flatten(), [0, 16, 32, 64]):
    if neighbours == 0:
        ax.plot(xs, ys, 'k.', markersize=2)
        ax.set_aspect('equal')
        ax.set_title("Scatter Plot")
    else:
        im, extent = nearest_neighbours(xs, ys, resolution, neighbours)
        ax.imshow(im, origin='lower', extent=extent, cmap=cm.jet)
        ax.set_title("Smoothing over %d neighbours" % neighbours)
        ax.set_xlim(extent[0], extent[1])
        ax.set_ylim(extent[2], extent[3])
plt.show()
```

Comment: you need `import pandas as pd`   `df = pd.read_csv("heatmap.csv")` instead of `df = open("heatmap.csv", "r", encoding="utf8")`

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I had tried solutions like `df = pd.read_csv(df)` but got errors such as `KeyError: 0` for line `xs = df[0]` as result. The import lines are there, I have just not shown them in the code

Comment: do you have column headers in your csv or start the data from the very first row?

Comment: Yup I do: the first column has the header `Policies` and the second column has the header `Words`

Comment: so you need `xs = df['Policies'].to_numpy()` and `ys = df['Words'].to_numpy()`

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is not related to how heatmap works, but rather how you open that csv file.
I cannot see your imports and what open "points" to, but most likely you opened the csv file directly, which means you'll have to write the code to parse the csv file.

A rather easy and popular approach is to use the csv module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) or pandas (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

Comment: Thanks for the input. I had tried solutions like `df = pd.read_csv(df)` but got errors such as `KeyError: 0` for line `xs = df[0]` as result